# Issue with Tooltip Display in Chart.js Line Chart using react-chartjs-2

Tags: charts, tooltip, react-chartjs

I'm attempting to create a line chart using `chart.js` and `react-chartjs-2`, but I'm encountering an issue with the tooltip not displaying when hovering over the data points. Strangely, the tooltip does appear when I hover over certain areas on the chart.

[image]

Here's my chart configuration:

***Chart configuration:***

```js
options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tension: 0.4,
    showTooltip: true,

    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            mode: "nearest",
            intersect: false,
            backgroundColor: "#4D4D4D",
           },
    },
};

labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];

data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
         {
            data: [
                { x: "January", series: "Series C", y: 0, date: "2021-01-01", postMoney: 12345 },
                { x: "February", series: "Series A", y: 43, date: "2021-02-01", postMoney: 33324 },
                { x: "March", series: "Series B4", y: 55, date: "2021-03-01", postMoney: 142345 },
                { x: "April", series: "Series C3", y: 30, date: "2021-04-01", postMoney: 332334 },
                { x: "May", series: "Series A33", y: 77, date: "2021-05-01", postMoney: 1235545 },
                { x: "June", series: "Series B3", y: 80, date: "2021-06-01", postMoney: 33424 },
                { x: "July", series: "Series C4", y: 90, date: "2021-07-01", postMoney: 1233345 },
            ],

            fill: true,
            borderColor: "#F2AB64",
            borderWidth: 6,
            pointBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            pointBorderColor: "#F2AB64",
            pointBorderWidth: 1.5,
            pointRadius: 9,
            pointStyle: "circle",
        },
    ],
};
```

`react-chartjs-2`: "3.3.0",

`chart.js`: "3.6.0",

`react`: "17.0.2",